# PHP,PDO,MySQLi function dont insert to database

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, pdo, mysqli

I make code that using pdo to insert information to database and gain XSS protection.
now im few days look at the code and dont see the problem that make the code to not insert the requird information.
Here`s My code:

```
if ($register = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `accounts`(`id`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `salt`, `fullname`, `birthdate`, `gender`, `secure question`, `secure answer`, `asked`, `answered`, `lastlogin`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
                    $register->bind_param("ssssssddsdds", $username, $email, $password, $random_salt, $fullname, $birthdate, $gender, $question, $answer, $z, $z, $lastlogin);
                    // Execute the prepared query.
                    if (! $register->execute()) {
                        echo "אירעה שגיאה";
                        $register->close();
                    }else{
                    echo 'אתם נרשמתם בהצלחה!. לחצו <a href="http://shaloti.com/users/login/">כאן</a>';}
                    $register->close();
                }
```

And the connection code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
```

Thank you.

Comment: check `$mysqli->error`

Comment: Your question's title contains PDO and MySQLi. You're not using both APIs together I hope. Plus, if your `id` column is AI, change NULL to `''` and check for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mysqli_affected_rows` to get the number of inserted row, if any function fails, check for errors using `mysqli_error`

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `accounts`(`id`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `salt`, `fullname`, `birthdate`, `gender`, `secure question`, `secure answer`, `asked`, `answered`, `lastlogin`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
if ($register = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
    $register->bind_param("ssssssddsdds", $username, $email, $password, $random_salt, $fullname, $birthdate, $gender, $question, $answer, $z, $z, $lastlogin);
    // Execute the prepared query.
    if (!$register->execute()) {
        echo "אירעה שגיאה";
        die("execute() failed: ". mysqli_error($mysqli));
    }

    if(mysqli_affected_rows($register) > 0){
        echo 'אתם נרשמתם בהצלחה!. לחצו <a href="http://shaloti.com/users/login/">כאן</a>';
    }else{
        echo 'Did not inser any row';
    }
}else{
    die("prepare() failed: ". mysqli_error($mysqli));
}
```